# Error download python3.4 with wget

Tags: python, shell, centos, wget, tar

I want install python 3.4 on my CentOS. wget show me this text:

```
[root@5]# wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.1/Python-3.4.1.tar.xz
--2014-07-03 16:39:11--  https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.1/Python-3.4.1.tar.xz
Resolving www.python.org... 185.31.19.175
Connecting to www.python.org|185.31.19.175|:443... connected.
ERROR: certificate common name `*.c.ssl.fastly.net' doesn't match requested host name `www.python.org'.
To connect to www.python.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I use `--no-check-certificate`, but when i want extraxt `Python-3.4.1.tar.xz` see this error:

```
[root@5]# tar xvf Python-3.4.1.tar.xz
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Archive contains obsolescent base-64 headers
tar: Read 4828 bytes from Python-3.4.1.tar.xz
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

How Can i fix it ?

Comment: Something is strange at your site. When I wget this URL, I *don't* get this warning, nor do I need to specify `--no-check-certificate`. It seems that you connect over a transparent proxy that listens in to your SSL communications, and possibly corrupts your downloads.

Comment: there is a link here to install python on centos it may help http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/

Comment: I wget `https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.1/Python-3.4.1.tar.xz` with my other VPS without problem :(

Comment: Dear Padraic i doesn't havve poblem in install python with source code. i have problem in downloading Python source.

Comment: Sorry yes, I thought for some reason the tut used an alternative method.

Answer (score 0):

first install xz-devel. E.G. on CentOS:

`yum install xz-devel`

after that you need to extract with xz:

`xz -d Python-3.4.1.tar.xz`

and then you can tar normally.

`tar -xvf Python-3.4.1.tar`

Hope it helps.